# If $\|v\|_Y=(\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i^2)^{1/2}$ and $\|v\|_X=(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\lambda_ic_i^2)^{1/2}$, is $X$ compactly embedded into $Y$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal, compact-operators, eigenfunctions

Let $X,Y$ be Hilbert spaces, $X$ continuously and densely embedded into $Y$, and $(u_k)_k$ be a complete orthogonal system in $V$ and an orthonormal basis of $Y$ s.t. $\langle u_k,u_l\rangle_X=\lambda_k\delta_{kl}$ and $\langle u_k,u_l\rangle_Y=\delta_{kl}$ for some $0<\lambda_1\le\lambda_2\le\cdots\to\infty$.

If $v\in X$, we can show $\left\|v\right\|_Y=\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i^2\right)^{1/2}$ and $\left\|v\right\|_X=\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\lambda_ic_i^2\right)^{1/2}$, where $c_i:=\langle v,u_i\rangle_Y$.

> Are we able to conclude that the embedding of $X$ into $Y$ is compact?

Comment: Yes, you can, e.g., prove that the unit ball of $X$ is precompact in $Y$ or that the inclusion is the norm-limit of the finite rank operators $x\mapsto \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \langle x,u_i\rangle u_i$.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure how we can prove your latter suggestion. Clearly, the operator $T_n:=\sum_{i=1}^nu_i\otimes u_i$, where $u_i\otimes u_i:X\to Y$, $x\mapsto\langle x,u_i\rangle_Yu_i$, converges in the strong operator topology to the inclusion $T:X\to Y$. But why does it even converge in the uniform operator topology?

Comment: @Jochen I first thought we might be able to show that $T$ is nuclear, but since $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|u_n\otimes u_n\right\|_{\mathfrak L(X,\:Y)}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|u_n\right\|_X\left\|u_n\right\|_Y=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sqrt{\lambda_n}$, this doesn't seem to be the case (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Essentially, you are dealing with *diagonal operators* $(x_n)_n\mapsto (c_nx_n)_n$ on $\ell^2$. Such an operator is compact iff $c_n\to 0$ and it is nuclear iff $\sum |c_n|<\infty$. The latter condition is called (or at least related to) the *Grothendieck-Pietsch criterion*.

Comment: @Jochen Yes, I know that. But $\lambda_n\to\infty$, and not $\lambda_n\to0$, and for the same reason it doesn't hold $\sum_n\lambda_n<\infty$. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe that one should apply the mentioned facts to $c_n=1\lambda_n$ -- but I did not really check.

Comment: @Jochen Sorry, I cannot follow. Which "mentioned" facts do you mean? And did you intentionally put the "$1$" before the $\lambda_n$? As I wrote before, neither $c_n\to0$ nor $\sum|c_n|<\infty$ does hold for $c_n=\lambda_n$. Are you unsure whether the claim is true? From your first comment, I thought you would claim that it is true.

Comment: Sorry, I intended to write $c_n=1/\lambda_n$ and the *mentioned facts* refer to the compactness and nuclearity of diagonal operators on $\ell^2$.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks for clarifying. With this choice of $c_n$, it clearly holds $c_n\to0$. But why is that relevant here? The natural isometric isomorphism between $X$ and $\ell^2$ is $U(v):=\left(\left\langle x,\frac{e_n}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}\right\rangle_X\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}=\left(\sqrt{\lambda_n}\left\langle x,e_n\right\rangle_Y\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ for $x\in X$. Since it seems like you know how to answer this question, I would be really thankful if you could elaborate on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u_k$ is a complete orthogonal system in $X$ and an orthonormal basis in $Y$ with $\langle u_k,u_l \rangle_X =\lambda_k \delta_{j,k}$, then $\|u_k\|=\sqrt{\lambda_k}$ so that $e_k=\lambda_k^{-1/2} u_k$ is an orthonormal basis of $X$. Identifying $\ell^2 \cong X$ (mapping the standard unit sequence to $e_k$) and $Y\cong \ell^2$ (mapping $u_k$ to standard unit sequence), the inclusion of $X$ into $Y$ becomes the diagonal operator $\ell^2\to\ell^2$ mapping a sequence $(x_k)_k$ to $(\lambda_k^{-1/2} x_k)_k$. This is compact if and only of $\lambda_k^{-1/2}\to 0$ (i.e., $\lambda_k\to\infty$) and it is nuclear if and only if $\sum_k |\lambda_k^{-1/2}|<\infty$ by Grothendieck-Pietsch.

Comment: Note that you wrote "is compact if and only if" twice; the latter shoulbe "is nuclear", I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, the reason why I was struggling was that I've mistakenly considered $u_k$ as being ortho*normal* in $Y$ and ortho*gonal* in $X$ (instead the other way around) in my notes. That's why I've repeatedly argued that $\sqrt{\lambda_n}$ does not converge to $0$ in my comments below the question ...